# What is the difference between the -d, -e , and -f flags in test / [ in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd

What is the difference between `-d`, `-e`, `-f` in shell scripting? I am trying to understand difference between `-e`, `-d` and `-f` parameters.

Examples: `if [ -d /path ]`, `if [ -e /path/ ]`, `if [ -f /path ]`

As per my knowledge

- `-d` checks for the directory existence
- `-e` checks for directory along with content (if a directory exists with contents then return true)
- `-f` checks for file existence

Comment: The docs you're looking for are in `man test`

Answer (score 14):

There are several different types of objects than can live in a file system. Regular files and directories are just two of them; others include pipes, sockets, and various device files. Here's an example using pipes to illustrate the differences between the three options. `-e` just checks if the named argument exists, regardless of what it actually is. `-f` and `-d` require its argument to both exist and be of the appropriate type.

```
$ mkfifo pipe   # Create a pipe
$ mkdir my_dir  # Create a directory
$ touch foo.txt # Create a regular file
$ [ -e pipe ]; echo $?   # pipe exists
0
$ [ -f pipe ]; echo $?   # pipe exists, but is not a regular file
1
$ [ -d pipe ]; echo $?   # pipe exists, but is not a directory
1
$ [ -e my_dir ] ; echo $?  # my_dir exists
0
$ [ -f my_dir ] ; echo $?  # my_dir exists, but is not a regular file
1
$ [ -d my_dir ] ; echo $?  # my_dir exists, and it is a directory
0
$ [ -e foo.txt ] ; echo $?  # foo.txt exists
0
$ [ -f foo.txt ] ; echo $?  # foo.txt exists, and it is a regular file
0
$ [ -d foo.txt ] ; echo $?  # foo.txt exists, but it is not a directory
1
```

You didn't ask about it, but there is a `-p` option to test if an object is a pipe.

```
$ [ -p pipe ]; echo $?    # pipe is a pipe
0
$ [ -p my_dir ]; echo $?  # my_dir is not a pipe
1
$ [ -p foo.txt ]; echo $?  # foo.txt is not a pipe
1
```

---

Other types of entries, and the command used to test for them:

- block special file (`-b`)
- character special file (`-c`)
- socket (`-S`)
- symbolic link (`-h` and `-L` both work the same; I don't recall the history of why both are defined.)

Comment: I would like to check dir exists with content then move content to backup dir else create new dir mkdir -p /testdir. could you please share some sample code.

Comment: @SivakumarReddy, if you're having difficulty with a script you're writing, please include the script [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43017199/edit) or in [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

It's all explained in "man test", alternatively spelled as "man [".

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?test